# Creating a number-puzzle that can scale to be greater/less (i.e. Can be adjusted for bigger puzzles)

Tags: math, equation, puzzle

I'm trying to create a scale-able picture puzzle ([like this](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=8+puzzle&oq=8+puzzle&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4567j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)) but can't figure out an equation to use to cover more than 3x3 and 4x4. I'm generating the puzzle dynamically based on the number of tiles I want to add (for instance 8 for a 3x3 and 15 for a 4x4).

So far to generate the rows I simply divide the tile number by the row/col number.

The hard part is doing the columns.

Here is the column equation I have used:

```
A = Tile Number Index (Start at 0 and end at 8 for 3x3)
B = Row/Col (3 for 3x3)

//A and B are both ints to start. The final divide B/() I convert to float
and then use a rounding to get the final number

(B/((A/B+1)*B-A))-1
```

- Here is what rows need to be like for 3x3: 000 111 222
- Here is what columns need to look like for 3x3: 012 012 012
- If using a 4x4 columns would look like this: 0123 0123 0123 0123
- etc.

This equation only works for a 3x3 puzzle. I have another equation for 4x4 but it doesn't scale at all. How can I fix this up and make all larger puzzles scale.

Comment: I do not understand at all what you are asking. Could you explain this in another way?

Comment: [This link here](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=8+puzzle&oq=8+puzzle&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4567j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is what i'm creating.

I'm adding the puzzle pieces dynamically. I have a for-loop setup to start at 0 and end at 8.

I need help with the equation that determines where to place the pieces (in order) and already have the rows part figured out. I need to be able to scale the size when required using the same equation. I'm asking what modifications I need to make to the equation above. Sorry I'm having a hard time explaining it.

Comment: That's a little better. Do you mean you want 15 tiles for the 4x4 board? (You said 24 which is much too many.) Do you mean for any number on a tile you want the row and column where that tile will end up when the puzzle is solved? If so, why do the rows start at zero but the columns start at one?

Comment: Great observation, I'm using unreal engine for my UI and the grid panel they provide starts columns at 1 for an unknown reason to me. I have since changed that to a different grid panel which starts both at 0. As for stating 24 tiles that was a accident. I meant 15 as you said. Also getting the r/c from the number tile is exactly what I'm looking for. It's how I determine where in the grid they will be placed. I will update the question with the fixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are working on the 8 or 15 puzzle (as in your link), you want to find the row and column where a tile will end up when the puzzle is solved, and the tile numbers, rows, and columns all start at zero. (This is what I gather from your last comment and your last edit.) If so, you could use, in Python,

```
def tile_end_coords(tilenum):
    '''Return the row and column coordinates for the end (solved) tile given
    its number. Global variable *n* is the number of squares on each side
    of the square puzzle.'''
    row = tilenum // n
    col = tilenum % n
    return row, col
```

The expression for `row` is the quotient after an integer division. Some languages, such as Object Pascal, use `div` rather than `//`. In some languages you would need to use `int(tilenum / n)`.

The expression for `col` is the remainder after an integer division. Some languages, such as Object Pascal, use `mod` rather than `%`. In some languages you would need to use `tilenum - row * n`.

I showed you some easy-to-understand, more portable code. In Python you could replace the entire function with just one line:

```
row, col = divmod(tilenum, n)
```

If the tile numbers, rows, or columns are one-based rather than zero-based, just add or subtract `1` in the appropriate places--it should be clear where.

Comment: Thank you so much! I always forget about modulus. That works perfectly!